# Spring security schema does not implement NameSpaceHandler

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to experiment with spring security when war is deployed on JBOSS following error is thrown

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1406)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        ... 25 more
```

POM file is as follows

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Security xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
...
</beans>
```

Spring-context 4-2-6.jar is present in both EAR and WAR. But Spring-Security jar is present in only jar

Am I missing from adding some jars?

Comment: For starters stop mixing framework versions (spring security 3.1.0 and 3.2.7). Also if the jar is present in multiple layers you eventually will run into some nice classcast issues. If a class is contained in 2 classloaders those classes aren't the same.

Comment: Have all same version now. But still same error

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was loading Spring within OSGI bundle as well as it was installed on server. So try to have only one copies of jar installed and referred.